# Align divs vertically usign bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The last two white rectangles divs aren't aligned with the others at [stirringminds.com/partners](http://stirringminds.com/partners)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-2 listwords" style="position:relative;top:32px;margin-bottom:50px;">
<button id="showall" class="active" style="font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;border:none;">ALL DEALS&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">BUSINESS&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show2" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">DESIGN&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show3" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">DEVELOPMENT&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show4" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">MARKETING&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show5" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">SALES&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show6" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">SUPPORT&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show7" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">PRODUCTIVITY&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show8" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">DIY&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show9" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">LEARNING&nbsp;</button>
<button id="show10" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">LIFE&nbsp;</button>
</div>

<a href="https://aws.amazon.com" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:27%;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/aws_logo_web_300px.png"/></div><div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">Amazon Web Services<br><span style="color:#888;">Up to $1000 credits for 1 year.</span></div></div></a>

<a href="https://www.ameyo.com/" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:35%;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Ameyo-emerge-logo-white.png"/></div><div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">Ameyo Emerge<br><span style="color:#888;">3 free Ameyo Emerge licenses for 3 months.</span></div></div></a>

<a href="https://www.cliklawyer.com/" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:25%;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cl.png"/></div><div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">Clik Lawyer<br><span style="color:#888;">10% discount on all money recovery matters.</span></div></div></a>

<a href="https://cloud.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:18%;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://stirringminds.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/gcplogo1-300x300-e1496441677297.jpg"/></div><div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">Google Cloud Platform<br><span style="color:#888;">10% discount on all money recovery matters.</span></div></div></a>

<a href="https://aws.amazon.com" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:27%;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/aws_logo_web_300px.png"/></div><div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">Amazon Web Services<br><span style="color:#888;">Up to $1000 credits for 1 year.</span></div></div></a>

<a href="https://www.ameyo.com/" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:35%;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Ameyo-emerge-logo-white.png"/></div><div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">Ameyo Emerge<br><span style="color:#888;">3 free Ameyo Emerge licenses for 3 months.</span></div></div></a>

<a href="https://www.cliklawyer.com/" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:25%;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cl.png"/></div><div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">Clik Lawyer<br><span style="color:#888;">10% discount on all money recovery matters.</span></div></div></a>

<a href="https://cloud.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:18%;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://stirringminds.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/gcplogo1-300x300-e1496441677297.jpg"/></div><div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">Google Cloud Platform<br><span style="color:#888;">10% discount on all money recovery matters.</span></div></div></a>

</div>
</div>
```

How can I align them with the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your source - I see you have the left box properly wrapped in a column - but you don't have the right hand column wrapped. They need to total 12 columns together.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"> LEFT HAND CONTENT</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">All of your buttons go here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added the col-md-10 on the place you told me and now it is aligned but it has less width, can you see it over at stirringminds.com/partners pls?

Comment: Simple, because your elements are still `col-md-4`. you should specify `col-md-5` if you want to use `col-md-10` as the parent div.

Comment: No problem @RuiFarinha, supporter of Korgrue

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way is to add a spacer:

```
<div class="col-md-2 dealsdiv">&nbsp;</div>
```

before

```
<div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;">
   <div class="col-xs-4" style="position:relative;top:25%;">
      <img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cl.png">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8" style="position:relative;top:15%;">
      Clik Lawyer<br>
      <span style="color:#888;">
          10% discount on all money recovery matters.
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

But the neatest way is to have 3 columns.

One for the navigation (`col-md-2`), then the remaining two columns (`col-md-5`) would be your content with four rows each.

Comment: hey this would work if the divs were static. Whenever you press a word from the list, it will filter the rectangles and in this case, when it loads the div with the spacer, it gets deformatted